# How to express that a map file depends on add_executable?

Tags: cmake, map-files

I'm building an executable using the standard command:

```
add_executable(MyExe a.c b.c)
```

I'm adjusting the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to emit a map file, and it works.

If I delete the map file, though, performing an incremental build doesn't regenerate the map file.  This makes sense, since I haven't expressed to cmake that the map file depends on MyExe.  In the above scenario, the MyExe.map isn't even a target, so cmake doesn't even know it exists.

I've tried creating a custom target, but I can't create a custom command that regenerates the map file, since it comes from `add_executable()`.  I then tried to use `add_dependencies()`, but that seems to only influence the build order.

I could explicitly re-run the linker as a custom command that builds a custom target, but that seems wasteful since linking does take a bit of time.

It almost seems like I need some way to tell add_executable that there are more outputs than just the executable image.  Is there a way to do this?

If anybody could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!  Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Man, this is the same problem I'm having. Are you working on Solaris?

Comment: "I'm adjusting the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS to emit a map file" - please show the code for this.  How long does linking take?  Are you using the Gold linker?  If not, it is much faster.

Comment: @jww Are you looking for a cross-platform way to generate Mapfiles with CMake and then use that as an input for a custom command? Maybe I just got it wrong, but your problem sounds different from the one described in the question.

Comment: Well, we don't distribute a mapfile. Rather, we build it on the fly when needed and write it to disk (in the GNU makefile). So we would like to generate the map file and make the program (*.exe) and shared object (*.so) a dependency of the mapfile.

Comment: @jww Added an alternative to my answer that also covers your use case (for makefile generators).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've seen the same question was also asked on [CMake's mailing list](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2014-May/057550.html) and never received an answer. So let me try to answer it here.

CMake doesn't have an official support for map files nor - if you add the necessary linker flags manually - to have more then one output of an executable target.

If you don't want to add it as an extra custom command/target step, you could link to an object file being part of you executable with [`OBJECT_OUTPUTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_OUTPUTS.html) source file property (works unfortunately only with Makefile generators).

I've successfully tested the following example with a GNU toolchain:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(MapFileDep)

file(WRITE "main.cpp" "int main() { return 0; }")

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(
        CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS 
        "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=output.map"
    )
endif()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    set_source_files_properties(
        "main.cpp" 
        PROPERTIES OBJECT_OUTPUTS "output.map"
    )
endif()
```

**Alternative**

And here the more advanced alternative (also covering @jww's use case):

Add something that generates/creates/copies the `output.map` file (when it's not there) and use [`LINK_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) target property to make CMake aware of re-linking when `output.map` changes:

```perl
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "output.map"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "output.map"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "output.map")

set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PROPERTIES 
        LINK_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.map"
)
```